# ​[http] is no longer supported

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

The [http](/questions/tagged/http) tag has no tag wiki/excerpt and 19 questions about various topics. Since [Stack Exchange doesn't work over HTTP anymore](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292058/295232) for quite a while now, isn't it time to burninate this tag? I see some questions which should receive the [https](/questions/tagged/https)/[ssl](/questions/tagged/ssl) tag, for others [architecture](/questions/tagged/architecture) might be more appropriate.

Comment: Links can still be HTTP I suppose, but then again, HTTPS would work just as well for those I presume.

Answer (score 1):

Links can still be HTTP I suppose, but then again, HTTPS would work just as well for those I presume, if it is about insecure / secure.

More importantly, anything to do with HTTP - *the protocol* - might still warrant the tag. If there are any bugs in that then I'd expect [http](/questions/tagged/http). HTTPS is nothing more than HTTP over TLS after all. There are quite a few questions about that (HTTP headers, HTTP error codes) etc. Tagging bugs in the HTTP protocol as [architecture](/questions/tagged/architecture) doesn't make much sense to me; that's about implementation, not architecture.

Of course, I'd imagine that the low number of questions is a problem, and if we go this way then the tag should get a description.

Comment: Ah, you mean like [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309980/295232). Perhaps we could use a separate tag for that, one that is less likely to be chosen? I get the feeling that most users don't read tag descriptions at all ...

Comment: There are questions mentioning HTTP results as well, and such, but yes, that was the first one that I saw. I cannot think of a better tag name than [tag:http] for HTTP related questions to be honest. If tag descriptions are not read than that's an issue in itself - I'm not sure we should fix it by mucking with the tag names.